# Angular2 can't see images after using ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular

I upload my angular2 project to my webhost, but for some reason i can't see images on my website. Rest of the website works fine. The dist folder that comes after using ng build --prod does not contain my image folder that was in src/app/images location.

Comment: try adding it to the assets folder like assets/imgs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy `images` folder to `assets`, or link as asset in `.angular-cli.json` file.

If you copy to `assets` your path will be `<img src="assets/images/path-to-abc.png">`

For 2nd option, you can refer this document: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration